# Create a hash do define groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe consisting of several meta information. If all features are the same, that row belongs to one group.

Assume this dataframe for a simplified example:

```py
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"feature1": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"]
                        , "feature2": [1,2,1,3,1,3]})
```

I would now like to create a marker that is different for every different combination, so including my marker columns, I'd expect this dataframe

```py
expected_result = pd.DataFrame({"feature1": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"]
                                   , "feature2": [1,2,1,3,1,3]
                                   , "hash": ["ab", "jk", "ab", "lu", "la", "lu"]})
```

```
   feature1   feature2  hash
0   A         1         ab
1   A         2         jk
2   A         1         ab
3   B         3         lu
4   B         1         la
5   B         3         lu
```

def create_uniqueID(x, y, z):
    if x is None:
        x = "*"
    else:
        x = str(x)
    if y is None:
        y = "*"
    else:
        x = str(x)
    if z is None:
        z = "_"
    else:
        x = str(x)
    return x+y+z

naturally I thought about hashing those data and therefore tried this:

```py
def create_uniqueID(x, y):
    if x is None:
        x = "_"
    if y is None:
        y = "_"
    return hash(tuple([x,y]))

data["marker"] = data.apply(create_uniqueID(data.feature1, data.feature2))
```

But than I get feedback, that Series are mutable and therefore cannot be hashed. So I assume that I have to do it elementwise,  but I have no clue how to do this in a concise and efficient way.

It is possible to get all the values for each column, hash them and re-attach them but I don't think that this is a nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use lambda function for processing each row separately:

```
data["marker"] = data.apply(lambda x: create_uniqueID(x.feature1, x.feature2), axis=1)
print (data)

  feature1  feature2               marker
0        A         1 -6565221176676644544
1        A         2 -6565221176675562019
2        A         1 -6565221176676644544
3        B         3  4352711037653751181
4        B         1  4352711037651586131
5        B         3  4352711037653751181
```

Another idea is use lambda function, but before replace `None`s to `_`:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 10000
L = list('abcdef') + [None]
data = pd.DataFrame({'feature1': np.random.choice(L, N),
                     'feature2':np.random.randint(100, size=N)})
#print (data)

data["marker1"] = data.fillna('_').apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)
print (data)
     feature1  feature2              marker1
0        None        73 -2622163292899442353
1           f        93  6883629009348118745
2        None        73 -2622163292899442353
3           c        95  8232223848018743176
4           e        95 -4199008080420766281
      ...       ...                  ...
9995        e        42 -4199008080510615856
9996        b        65 -2981575294812687977
9997        c        95  8232223848018743176
9998     None        19 -2622163292940578303
9999     None        61 -2622163292990374453

[10000 rows x 3 columns]
```

Performance for 10k rows is different, it depends of length of DataFrame:

```
np.random.seed(123)

def create_uniqueID(x, y):
    if x is None:
        x = "_"
    if y is None:
        y = "_"
    return hash(tuple([x,y]))

N = 10000
L = list('abcdef') + [None]
data = pd.DataFrame({'feature1': np.random.choice(L, N),
                     'feature2':np.random.randint(100, size=N)})
#print (data)

data["marker0"] = data.apply(lambda x: create_uniqueID(x.feature1, x.feature2), axis=1)
data["marker1"] = data.fillna('_').apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)

data['hash1'] = [hash(''.join(str(y) for y in x[1].values)) for x in data.iterrows()]
data['hash2'] = data.apply(lambda x: hash(str(x.feature1)+str(x.feature2)), axis=1)

print (data)

In [183]: %timeit data.apply(lambda x: create_uniqueID(x.feature1, x.feature2), axis=1)
332 ms ± 25.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [184]: %timeit data.fillna('_').apply(lambda x: hash(tuple(x)), axis=1)
212 ms ± 17.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [185]: %timeit [hash(''.join(str(y) for y in x[1].values)) for x in data.iterrows()]
996 ms ± 113 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [186]: %timeit data.apply(lambda x: hash(str(x.feature1)+str(x.feature2)), axis=1)
326 ms ± 8.09 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"feature1": ["A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"],
                     "feature2": [1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3]})

data['hash'] = [hash(''.join(str(y) for y in x[1].values)) for x in data.iterrows()]
```

Or, as an alternative

```
data['hash'] = data.apply(lambda x: hash(str(x.feature1)+str(x.feature2)), axis=1)
```

Result:

```
  feature1  feature2                 hash
0        A         1  8263268926816845868
1        A         2 -8020701168240960676
2        A         1  8263268926816845868
3        B         3 -4924655571523756344
4        B         1  6029195539680549382
5        B         3 -4924655571523756344
```

Performance:

[image]

Comment: hmmm, try test in for 10k data

Answer (score 0):

> I would now like to create a marker that is different for every different combination

In pandas, `groupby()` has the `ngroup()` method, which enumerates the groups it found. Hashing isn't necessary.

```py
data['marker'] = data.groupby(['feature1', 'feature2']).ngroup()
```

Here's the result:

```
  feature1  feature2  marker
0        A         1       0
1        A         2       1
2        A         1       0
3        B         3       3
4        B         1       2
5        B         3       3
```